# How to make Peity chart resposive?

Tags: jquery, svg, charts

I have used the Peity-Chart library in my project and they are working fine but I am facing problem in making them responsive as they are built with svg. When I change height width to % charts shows with default height width (16x16). I tried to change height width with jquery/javascript but its not working. Is there any way to make these charts responsive. Library link is as follow:
[Peity-chart](http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/jQuery-Plugin-for-Converting-Content-into-Canvas-Element-peity.html)

My Js code for this charts as follow:

```
$(".pie").peity("pie",{width:'800',height:'400'});
$(".donut").peity("donut",{width:'800',height:'400'});
$(".line").peity("line",{width:'800',height:'400'});
$(".bar").peity("bar",{width:'800',height:'400'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() <= 768 ) {
        $("span.pie").peity("pie", {width: '100', height: '100'});
    } else {
        $("span.pie").peity("pie", {width: '300', height: '300'});
    }
})
```